# grep first n rows, return file name only

Tags: regex, linux, search, grep

I can do the following to search for what I need and return the file name:
grep -l "mysearchstring" ./*.xml
However the files I am searching are huge so this takes forever.  The string I am searching will appear in the first 200 rows so how can I search only the first 200 rows and still return the file name?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
for file in *.xml; do
   head -200 "$file" | grep -q "mysearchstring" && echo "$file"
done
```